# linker command failed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

My xcode stopped responding so I forced it to close, after i opened it and tried to build the program again it gives me the following error, Any can help please, Iam using Xcode 4.5 note that i built this app on xcode 4.4 and it worked before !

> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/../../../Downloads/RestKit-RestKit-991bd5c/Examples/RKDiscussionBoardExample/DiscussionBoard/Libraries/three20'
>   ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/../../../Downloads/RestKit-RestKit-991bd5c/Specs/Runner/OCMock'
>   ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/facebook-ios-sdk-lib'
>   ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/../../../../Downloads/TestFlightSDK1.0'
>   ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/omars/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libSSToolkit.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/omars/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libSSToolkit.a
>   ld: file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/omars/Desktop/libTestFlight.a for architecture armv7s
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: The entire rest kit build-folders (including its sub-libraries) should be removed and rebuild from the scratch. You may do that manually by simply removing its `build`-folder.

Comment: Not sure if this heps but "armv7s" is the instruction set supported by the new ARM processor in the iPhone 5. Xcode 4.5 by default generates binaries for armv7 and armv7s.

Comment: ..and by the way; combining an ugly monster like restkit with another nasty monster like three20 seems to be a certain way of getting into trouble. But then again, that is unrelated to your specific issue and just my personal opinion.

Comment: Thanks guys the problem was in the reskit itself, i have to get  the newer version of it to fix this issue because the current version does not support the armv7s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the restkit needs update to work on xcode 4.5 , after i reinstall the new version of it every thing works well

Answer (score 1):

Did you move any folders in your project, maybe by accident?  If rsswtmr's answer doesn't help, check the real location of some of the files/folder mentioned above (like OCMock) with the setting as seen in the project.  You can see where the project thinks they are by opening the "utilities" view (the right most of the 3 view buttons) in XCode 4.5.  Also, see if any filenames are displayed in red (indicating Xcode can't find them).

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if the project build settings were somehow munged, but when this happens the first thing I always do is do a complete clean (shift-cmd-option K) and re-build. That solves the issue 90% of the time.